# Accessing command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

please forgive me if this is a noob question, but i'm a beginner at C, learning only for a while. I tried to write a program that sums up two numbers (provided as params to the application). The code is like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
   int a = atoi(argv[0]);
   int b = atoi(argv[1]);
   int sum = a+b;
   printf("%d", sum);
   return 0;
}
```

But I get incorrect results - huge numbers even for small inputs like 5 and 10. What is wrong here?

Comment: For debugging a problem, make sure you print the inputs and the outputs.  The first thing to do would be to add '`printf("argv[0] = %s\n", argv[0]); printf("argv[1] = %s\n", argv[1]);` followed by `printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", a, b);` after the calls to `atoi()`.  Had you done that, you probably wouldn't have needed to ask the question.  (Don't forget to print a newline after the answer!).

Comment: Also, this is a C question; `#include <cstdlib>` is a C++ header.  Use `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first argument to the program is the name of the program itself. Try using the following instead.

```
int a = atoi(argv[1]); 
int b = atoi(argv[2]);
```

Comment: Aww, you win. Although now that I'm thinking about it, why is he getting "huge numbers"? Shouldn't `atoi(argv[0])` be `0` in pretty much all cases?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Yeah, I agree, but until this error is eliminated determining any other problem isn't going to be possible. Oh well, case solved.

Comment: I cannot. It says i need to wait 3 more minutes. Don't worry I will accept it. It helped me a lot!

Comment: @Nathon You need to wait [15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099) after asking a question before you can accept an answer

Answer (score 3):

Thats because argv[0] is the name of your executable.

You should use argv[1] and argv[2].

And make sure the count (argc)is 3.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

The first element in argv (`argv[0]`) is the [command itself](http://notabug.com/2002/coherent/man/argv.html).  This will be your program executable name...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of your program is `noob.c` and  you compile it with `gcc ./noob.c -o noob`.
You have to make these changes.

```
int a = atoi(argv[1]); 
int b = atoi(argv[2]);
```

You have to run it `./noob 1 2` and voila the output will be `3`.

argc is 3 viz number of command line arguments, your input will be the 1st and 2nd values from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `argv[0]` is the program name, not the first argument (i.e. if you run `myapp 4 5`, `argv` becomes `myapp`, `4`, `5`).