# New to IPC, can't get my pipe to work

Tags: c, ipc, pipe

Sorry for the length of this post...  I've encountered about a zillion problems in this.  Up front I'll say I'm a student and my professor is a worthless resource.  So, all I want to to do is have producer fork, then the parent producer will count some stuff in a file and send two ints to consumer, which was launched by the child process.  I've tested everything, the fork and the file stuff works and I have printf statements all over the place so I know what is being done and where the code is at.

When I added the

```
if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
   perror("pipe");
}
```

it caused my parent to just terminate.  It reaches "parent pipe open" but then it dies.  I checked with $ ps to see if it was just hung, but it's not there; it just dies.  If I take that snippet out, it runs to the end but I presume if that code isn't there, then it's not actually aware that pipefd is a pipe...  right?

I did search on this site and found another example of this and followed what he did as well as the answer and mine just refuses to work.  I'm pretty sure it's a trivially easy thing to fix but I've run out of ideas of what to try :(

I don't really want to post all my code because it'll be a huge wall of text but I don't want to accidentally cut something out that turns out to be important either.

producer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, stderr, fprintf */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h>     /* _exit, fork, execl */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno */
#include <string.h>     /* strlen */
#include <sys/wait.h>   /* wait */

#define SLEEP_TIME 8

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    //PID
    pid_t local_pid;
    local_pid = fork();

    //Logic to determine if the process running is the parent or the child
    if (local_pid == -1) {

        /* Error:
        * When fork() returns -1, an error happened
        * (for example, number of processes reached the limit).
        */
        fprintf(stderr, "can't fork, error %d\n", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    } else if (local_pid == 0) {

        //Child specific code
        int child;
        char *temp[] = {NULL};
        printf("Child PID found\n");
        child = execv("./consumer", temp); 

        _exit(0);


    } else {
        //Parent specific code
        printf("Parent running\n");
        //open file
        FILE * randStrings;
        randStrings = fopen("randStrings.txt", "r");
        int file_length;
        int num_of_e = 0;
        int c;          //using this as a char


        //until eof
        while (feof(randStrings) == 0) {
            c = fgetc(randStrings);
            //calculate length of file
            file_length++;
            //count e chars
            if (c == 'e') {
                num_of_e++;
            }
        }

        //close file
        fclose(randStrings);

        //send bundle to child
        int a[2];
        a[0] = num_of_e;
        a[1] = file_length;

        printf("num of e = %i\n", a[0]);
        printf("len = %i\n", a[1]);

        //set up parent pipe
        int pipefd[2];

        if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            printf("x\n");
        }
        printf("parent pipe open\n");
        close(pipefd[0]); //close the read end
        write(pipefd[1], &a[0], sizeof(int));
        write(pipefd[1], &a[1], sizeof(int));
        close(pipefd[1]);
        printf("parent pipe closed\n");

        //wait for child to finish running
        wait(NULL);
        printf("parent out\n");
        //terminate
    }
}
```

and consumer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, stderr, fprintf */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* pid_t */
#include <unistd.h>     /* _exit, fork, execl */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* exit */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno */

#define SLEEP_TIME 5

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    printf("Child program launched\n");

    //receive bundle
    int pipefd[2];
    int buf[2]; 

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        printf("child x\n");
    }

    close(pipefd[1]); //child closes write end

    buf[0] = 0;
    buf[1] = 0;

    /*int i = 0;        // i dont like this
    while (read(pipefd[0], &buf[i], sizeof(int)) > 0) {
        i++;
    }*/
    printf("child reading pipe\n");

    read(pipefd[0], &buf[0], sizeof(int));
    read(pipefd[0], &buf[1], sizeof(int));

    close(pipefd[0]);
    //buf should have the stuff in it
    int num_of_e = buf[0];
    int file_length = buf[1];
    printf("child num of e = %i\n", num_of_e);
    printf("child len = %i\n", file_length);

    //open file
    FILE * resultStrings;
    resultStrings = fopen("resultStrings.txt", "w");

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_e; i++) {
        //write num_of_e e chars
        fputc('e', resultStrings);
    }
    //or if no e chars, write - chars
    if (num_of_e == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < file_length; i++) {
            //write file_length '-' chars
            fputc('-', resultStrings);
        }
    }
    //close file
    fclose(resultStrings);
    printf("child out\n");
}
```

if you're still here after all that, you deserve a thank you just due to the length of this.

Comment: _professor is a worthless resource_  does that mean he/she never looks on SO?

Comment: @ryyker Do you think he knows who user2867890 is?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - LOL, Probably not. (but its pretty easy to search for a problem as specific as this one.)   I find in general, students who refer to their professors (or anyone else) in this way should look in the mirror.  (nice answer by the way, +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. The whole mechanism works because a child process inherits the parent's open file descriptors.

It should go like this:

- Open the pipe with `pipe(pipefd)`
- `fork()`

  - Parent (producer):

    - closes the read side (`pipefd[0]`)
    - writes to the write side (`pipefd[1]`)
  - Child (consumer):

    - closes the write side (`pipefd[1]`)
    - reads from the read side (`pipefd[0]`)     *or*     calls `exec`

You are opening distinct pipes in both the parent and child process (after you've `fork`ed.) It needs to happen before you `fork`.

Now since you're `exec`ing, the new process needs to be aware of read-only pipe. There are a couple ways you could do this:

- Pass it the file descriptor number (`pipefd[0]`) on the command line
- `dup2(1, fd)` it to be the stdin of the newly exec'd process

Comment: Okay, most of that makes sense.
So after exec, the consumer has no idea the pipe is there but I don't need to open it...  just use read(3, foo, bar);  right?

Comment: Right - `pipefd[0]` will *probably* be 3. However, there's nothing really guaranteeing that. Which is why I suggested passing it on the command line.

Comment: Our teacher also failed to teach us how to properly use exec (basically we've never been taught C, we've been taught Java and this guy, albeit correctly, thinks we need to learn C so he assigns all our homework in C... without any instruction or help).  So I'm pretty unclear about how I would pass with command line...  "./consumer -something"?  Then access it with argv[somethingelse]?

Comment: See the [man page for `execv`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execv.htm) Hint: you're already passing it nothing. (`char *temp[] = {NULL};`)

Comment: And searching for "c command line arguments" brings me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337915/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-c.